# Condition of being isomorphic to a submodule of a factor module?

Tags: modules

Suppose $M$ is module and $N$ a submodule over some commutative ring $R$. If $x\neq 0$, and $(x)\cap N=0$, why does this imply $(x)$ is isomorphic to some submodule of $M/N$? (Let's also assume that $M\neq 0$ and $N$ is a proper submodule.)

It was a quick detail in a passage I was reading, and I can't recall why it is.

Comment: What about the case $M=0$? Do you require $N$ to be a proper submodule?

Comment: @AlexBecker Sure, this is related to associated primes, so I'll say $M\neq 0$ and $M/N\neq 0$ as well.

Comment: My ring theory is a little rusty, to say the least, but if you let $K$ be the submodule generated by $x$ and $N$, then doesn't the "3rd isomorphism theorem" tell you that $(x) \cong K/N$?

Comment: @williamdemeo How would that follow exactly? I don't see why $(x)\cap N=0$ is needed in that case.

Comment: @ricky Because the isomorphism theorems tell you that $(x)/((x)\cap N) \cong K/N$.  If it's still not clear, let me know and I'll elaborate in a proper answer.

Comment: Actually, I mispoke.  I think it's the "2nd isomorphism theorem" that I was thinking of.  I should give a proper answer...

Comment: @williamdemeo I recall now, thanks. Feel free to give a proper answer though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general theorem is this (Hungerford p. 179):

If $B$ and $C$ are submodules of a module $A$ over a ring $R$ then 
there is an $R$-module isomorphism

$$B/B\cap C \cong (B+C)/C.$$

That $+$ notation looks weird to me, but i'm not a ring theorist :)  I would prefer to use $\langle B, C\rangle$ or $B\vee C$ and to view it as the "join" because the theorem is "obvious" if you draw the lattice of submodules, and because the theorem holds more generally, of course (though for groups make sure $C$ is normal in $\langle B, C\rangle$! :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sketch of a quick proof:

If $\pi: M \to M/N$ denotes the canonical projection and we set $\overline{x} = \pi(x)$, then $\text{im}(\pi|_{(x)}) = (\overline{x})$, and the latter is a submodule of $M/N$. Now, $\text{ker}(\pi|_{(x)}) = \text{ker}(\pi) \cap (x) = N \cap (x) = 0$, so $\pi|_{(x)}: (x) \to (\overline{x})$ is an isomorphism.